Angular-jest: single unit test takes 1500 sec to complete
I am new to angular unit testing with jest. And config the project with jest as stated below.
After every --clearCache, running a simple unit test takes 500 to 1500 sec. But after the 1st run unit test complete in 30sec. This mainly cause issue in running inside pipeline.
I have looked around found people where facing issue with old version of jest. And also tried tweaking but it didn't help.
unit test report
unit test report
unit test
describe('LoginPage', () => {
  let component: any;
  let harness: RouterTestingHarness;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SigninComponent, ToastComponent, InputComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule,BrowserAnimationsModule, RouterTestingModule,MyCommonLibModule FormsModule],
      providers: [
        provideRouter([{
          path: 'auth/signin',
          component: SigninComponent
        }]), Router,
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: { CognitoUserpoolLogin: jest.fn() } },
        { provide: AuthIntegrationService, useValue: { triggerEventOnLogin: jest.fn() } },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { params: of({ page: '' }), } }

      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    harness =  await RouterTestingHarness.create();
    component = await harness.navigateByUrl('auth/signin');
  });
  it('should create the app', async() => {
    expect(component).toBeInstanceOf(SigninComponent);
  });
})

package

"@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"jest-preset-angular": "^14.0.0",
"@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
"ts-node": "^10.9.2",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",

tsconfig.spec.ts

{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest" // 1
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true, // 2
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true // 3
  },
  "files": [
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

Jest Config

const esModules = ['ngx-otp-input','@angular', '@ngrx', "@mylib/my-common-lib", "@aws-amplify", "@aws-sdk", "ngx-cookie-service", "ngx-spinner", "primeng"];

const config: Config = {
modulePaths: ["<rootDir>"],
clearMocks: true,
collectCoverage: true,
coverageDirectory: "coverage",
coverageProvider: "v8",
moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules"
  ],
preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
testEnvironment: "jsdom",
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    `<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!${esModules.join('|')})`
  ],
}


Seconds or milliseconds?

seconds (attached unit test report image)

Why would you navigate and then run the test case, just do it directly! Create the component using createComponent and access the instance with fixture.debugElement.componentInstance
describe('LoginPage', () => {
  let component: any;
  let harness: RouterTestingHarness;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SigninComponent, ToastComponent, InputComponent],
      imports: [CommonModule,BrowserAnimationsModule, RouterTestingModule,MyCommonLibModule FormsModule],
      providers: [
        Router,
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: { CognitoUserpoolLogin: jest.fn() } },
        { provide: AuthIntegrationService, useValue: { triggerEventOnLogin: jest.fn() } },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { params: of({ page: '' }), } }

      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', async() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(component).toBeInstanceOf(SigninComponent);
  });
})


No improvement, still takes 1400 sec
